# Tensorflow Serving Client / Base64 Issue / Error 3

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'd like to get the following model up and running on Tensorflow Serving:

https://github.com/mdietrichstein/tensorflow-open_nsfw

I've exported the model using this code: https://github.com/mdietrichstein/tensorflow-open_nsfw/blob/master/tools/export_model.py

But I'm getting the following error when trying to compute a result using a node.js client:

```
{ code: 3, 
  details: 'Invalid character found in base64.\n\t 
  [[Node: map/while/DecodeBase64 = DecodeBase64[_output_shapes=[[]],
  _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](map/while/TensorArrayReadV3)]]',
  metadata: Metadata {
   _ internal_repr: {}
  }
}
```

The code for my client configured with the test server address can be found here:

https://github.com/delta9/tensorflow-serving-node-client

Did anyone face similar issues and if so, how did you solve it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use web safe base64 encode. 
    `base64.urlsafe_b64encode(open('test.jpg', 'rb').read())`
Because tensorflow.decode_base64 uses WEB-SAFE model to decode base64 encoding.
The official document for tensorflow.decode_base64 is:

*Decode web-safe base64-encoded strings.
  Input may or may not have padding at the end. See EncodeBase64 for padding.
  Web-safe means that input must use - and _ instead of + and /.*